# Is there a name for a application structure or design pattern for multilayer UI

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, structure

Is there a name for a application structure or design pattern for a multi-layer UI?

For exemple, lets say I have a web application using multiple layers of `<div­­>`:

Layer0 = background image,

Layer1 = Left button "<-",

Layer2 = Center button "*",

Layer3 = Right button "->"

All layers are the same size but they have different transparencies.

Layer0 would be 100% in size and all black,
Layer1 would be 100% in size but transparent with a "<-" arrow pointing left on one third of the screen,
Layer2 would be the same as Layer1 but with an "*" (dot) in the middle third of the screen
Layer3 would have the same as layer1 but arrow point right "->".

And by interacting with the screen, the client would change the layers order with, lets say javascript, the layers would change position to "bring up" certain element or even hide some by "bringing them down".

So layers order could be 1, 3, 0, 2 or it could even have more layer with static content inside them so the order could be 0, 5, 6, 1, 3, 25, 36, 19, 10, 8, 9... etc.

So is there a name for those application? or design pattern? or application structure?

And is this bad practice? (Ok, this is probably a matter of likes or dislikes) so lets change this for:

Is there a best case scenario where this would theoretically work best, or is there a case where this is not a good idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question.

The whole idea of using layers in design is to achieve separation. However, in ui frameworks, layers often literally just mean layers, as in what gets drawn on top of what.

Sounds like what you want to do is have a way to dynamically reorder the layers. So yeah, there are some possible design patterns you could consider.

The main one would be Chain of Responsibility. If you look at the section in the Gang of Four on this pattern, they in fact talk about many ui frameworks, including NextStep, which had the notion of a Responder Chain (which is now the backbone of iOS and MacOS).

In general, CoR is implemented with each member of the chain holding a reference only to its successor. So if you were going to allow people to reorder the elements, that would most likely be done through one more more splice operations. So you could easily define such an operation that would insert a layer in between two existing ones: it would have to put itself as the successor of the link it was going to follow and then set the next item as its own successor.

The other Design Pattern that might apply would be Decorator. Sometimes, you want to add something to what is being painted, but you still want to have the basic painting occur, for instance, scrolling is often added with a Decorator because the main panel can be unchanged, and the logic for which bars appear, where the thumbtacks are and how to respond to them, are completely isolated from the original drawing code.

The general point that covers both cases: separate the components by responsibility.

Comment: I like your answer it gave enought information so I can complete my research on the web many thanks to you!